# How to redirect user after file upload using PHP

Tags: php, redirect, upload

As the title says, I wish to redirect a user back to the main page after they have uploaded a file, so far, all this code does is display a page with the relevant information (File name, file size etc..) I want to redirect them to a custom success page.

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
 "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
 "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
 "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
 "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  header('Location: success.html');
  }
  }
 }
 else
 {
   echo "Invalid file";
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your success page is 'success.html', you can use:

```
    header('Location: success.html');
```

You need to remove ALL your echo lines, since it will cause you an 'headers already sent' exception.

From a workflow persepective, there is also no sense in echoing to the screen and then redirecting.

Remove the following lines:

```
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
```

Also you can store all file types in array and make your code much cleaner:

```
$allowedTypes = array("image/gif",..,..,"image/png");
```

and then use

```
in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"], $allowedTypes);
```

Full code:

```
<?
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$allowedTypes = array("image/gif",'..','..',"image/png");

$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"], $allowedTypes))
   && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
   && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
   echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{

if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
  else
  {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    header('Location: success.html');
  }
  }
}
else
{
echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I get this error now;    Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /srv/disk12/1369030/www/dayz-survivorguide.co.nf/upload_file.php:20) in /srv/disk12/1369030/www/dayz-survivorguide.co.nf/upload_file.php on line 33

Comment: You have to REPLACE the echo line. You can not set header after any output was made to the screen.

Comment: I have replaced the echo line, ill update my code now to help you out a bit more

Comment: You need to remove the other 4 echos as well. No sense in keeping them anyway if you are redirecting. They will cause an error. Read my revised answer.

Comment: Okay, sorry for being a pain, I reall appreciate your help, but it still doesn't redirect me, it just shows a blank page of the upload_file.php, I have updated my code again

Comment: That's because you didn't remove the 4 echo lines. I've just added the full code to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It finally works! Sorry for being a pain, as you can tell, I've only just started to learn PHP!:) Thanks again!