# when i submit form input type=file for send image with php i want redirect to an other page

Tags: javascript, php, html

when i submit form input type=file for send image with php i want redirect to an other page but the file was not send, I want to use "ACTION=index.php" but after having submit the form the page is well redirected but the images are not sent, basically what I want is to send the files and go to the next page, so logically using action you should redirect me directly to index.php it redirect me but without sending me files

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function() {
  var filename = $(this).val().split('\\').pop();
  $(this).next().find('span').html(filename);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                                    
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  ACTION=index.php>
<div class="containerid">

<div class="cardid">

  <div class="imgid">
<img class="idfront"src="assets\images\id-card-front.png" alt="">
                                                </div>
                                            
<input type="file" name="recto" id="recto" class="btnsend" />
<label for="recto" class="labelbtn"><span>Choisir le Recto</span></label>
                                    
                                            </div>
<div class="cardid">

<div class="imgid">
<img class="idfront"src="assets\images\id-card-back.png" alt="">
                                                </div>
                                        
<input type="file" name="verso" id="verso" class="btnsend" />
<label for="verso" class="labelbtn"><span>Choisir le Verso</span></label>
                                            </div>
<div class="cardid">   
                                                
<div class="imgid">
<img class="idfront"src="assets\images\Asset171.png" alt="">
                                                    </div>

<input type="file" name="selfie" id="selfie" class="btnsend" />
<label for="selfie" class="labelbtn"><span>Choisir le Selfie</span></label>
                                            </div>
                                    
                                    
                                    </div><br>
                                        
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="sendall"/> 


                                    
                                </form>
```

Comment: $_POST and $_FILES only exist in the script you first go to, so in your case `index.php` if you then redirect to another script, you will have to push data into the session or in the case of the file, move it to its destination in the first script

Comment: Dont think your CSS is overly relevant to the question so I removed it

Comment: Related question: [Why would $_FILES be empty when uploading files to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php)

Comment: You need to POST to a page that handles your file upload, then when it is done, redirect to the next page.  If you search for "*php file upload redirect*" you will find many answers here already showing how to do that, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275562/php-redirect-page-after-files-are-uploaded, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114135/how-to-redirect-a-php-file-upload-form-to-url, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367866/how-to-redirect-user-after-file-upload-using-php, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63819906/redirect-php-script-after-file-upload ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP redirect page after files are uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275562/php-redirect-page-after-files-are-uploaded)

Answer (score 0):

you can handle this in **php** file after checking your fields validation:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $contact = $_POST['contact'];
  $address = $_POST['address'];
  if($name !=''&& $email !=''&& $contact !=''&& $address !='')
    {
      //  To redirect form on a particular page
      header("Location:https://www.formget.com/app/");
    }
?>
```